# How to remove the sleep habit against prayer?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

I have a big problem where I usually miss Dhuhr prayer or pray Dhuhr 10 minutes before Asr prayer because I always delay my alarm.

For example, if Dhuhr is at 11:30am and Asr is at 3:00pm, I would put the alarm at 11:20am but when the alarm wakes me up I put it on 2:00pm and then end up waking up and praying 10 minutes before Asr prayer.

I am a woman who doesn't have a job and is not married. My sleeping pattern is not so good, I usually sleep after praying Fajr and then wake up at Asr. I know it's bad, I'm trying my best to fix it.

Can you please give me advice to remove this sleeping habit where I miss Dhuhr? I feel really bad about missing prayer due to sleep, will I be punished?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You shouldn't wake up that late. Allah made the night for rest and day for labour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe better to put your alarm clock far from bed, and setting it to be louder should wake you up.

Or do dhikr of Allah after you wake up, then do wudu and if you want, you can pray duha if there is enough time, or just pray Zuhr If there's no time for duha.

If you wake up and remember Zuhr (If it is Zuhr Salah time) but go back to sleep, you are committing a major sin, but if a person is saving another person's life, and it is Salah time but the person delays it in order to save someone's life, then there is no sin on the person who is saving someone's life.

If you struggle to fall asleep, then do dhikr of Allah, this will help you fall asleep.

If a person forgets a Salah, he should pray it as soon as he remembers it, but if he delays it, then it is a sin.